# JavaScript display html text input in html5 output tag

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to make a little JavaScript web app that I can use to make templates for webpages I am going to make.(To speed up designing and stuff.)
But when doing this I want to make it update live while I am typing. I know it can be done with [this](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_live_text_input), but I think it is a little messy. So i am trying to use the html5 output element instead, but i can't make it compatible with text strings instead of only numbers.
The following only works with numbers:

```
<html>
    <body>
         <form oninput="x.value=parseInt(a.value)+parseInt(b.value)">
             <input type="range" name="a" value="50">
             <input type="number" name="b" value="50">
             <output name="x" for="a b"></output>
         </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

PS: i am a newbie in JS and it only needs to be compatible with FF.

Comment: Ever thought of using Jquery, it would be a cinch to do?

Comment: Try jsfiddle.net to test and explain

Comment: so You want to make tool like Adobe Dreamweaver on web page? Do I understand You well?

Comment: More info here http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/05/12/fixing-oninput-in-ie9-using-html5widgets/

Comment: @WojciechDłubacz no, just simple stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fv9c4/)

```
<form oninput="xx.value=aa.value+bb.value">
    <input type="text" name="aa" value="hello">
    <input type="text" name="bb" value="world">
    <output name="xx" for="aa bb"></output>
</form>
```